# Understanding sections of fiber bundles

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, lie-groups

I need some explanation of the meaning of sections of the following situation of fiber bundles;

Let $G$ be a topological group such that $G=N\times Z$ where $N$ is normal and $Z$ is central subgroups. Let $H<G$ be a closed subgroup and let $J:=N_G(H^0)$ be the normalizer of the identity component of $H$ then $Z<J$. Now consider the following fibration:
$$G/H\to G/J$$ 
$$gH\mapsto gJ$$ 
The fiber here is $J/H$.
I was reading somewhere the following "since  $N$-orbits intersect the fiber $J/H$ in only one point i.e, $eH$, then $N$-orbits are sections of the fibration"  Here $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

I don't really understand this. It will be very helpful if you explain it to me. Thanks

Comment: what is $N$ here ?

Comment: A normal subgroup of $G$. I will add this to the question.

Comment: $N$ is really any normal subgroup ?

Comment: In fact, $G=N\times Z$ where $Z$ is central. Sorry maybe this is important.

Comment: what is the relation between $J$ and $Z$ is $J\subset Z$?

Comment: Actually, $J$ contains the center. One more fact that I didn't mention is that $J$ is the normalizer of the identity component of $H$. i.e, $J=N_G(H^0)$.

Comment: Why are these things not mentioned in the question?

Comment: Sorry, since I thought section can be defined without knowing what are the subgroups.

Comment: @TsemoAristide   I edited the question, if you can help that would be great. Thanks